# Algorithm to solve linear n equation having n variables

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

I got stuck in one step while writing one algorithm. Please help me solve that.

I need to solve linear equations. Please see below image.

[image]

I used image because I don't know how to write matrix.

Please suggest me algorithm to calculate all the variables value. Looking for your kind response.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Comment: If this is not related to programming, then this is not the right place to ask

Comment: How about showing some code? What did you try? Where are your problems exactly?

Comment: @P0W Yes this is related to programming. I need to solve this for any number of variables.

Comment: @Matthias As I said this is subproblem of my main problem. I need to use variables vector result.

Comment: @All Please don't vote this question as off-topic, as this is programming question. If you think it is related to any other stackexchange site, please transfer this.

Comment: Your matrix is both symmetric and a Toeplitz matrix. Google for some efficient algorithms that exploit this fact.

Comment: If invertible, `Ax = b` yields `x = A^(-1) b`

Comment: I'd vote BlackBear's answer if it was an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your matrix is always of the same form given in the question (i.e. all ones, except for -1 along the diagonal), then you can solve it in time O(n) where n is the number of equations.

Let N be the number of equations.

Then the solution is given by:

```
t = (a+b+c)/(N-2)
x = (t-a)*0.5
y = (t-b)*0.5
z = (t-c)*0.5
```

Python code:

```
# Set up equations
a=4
b=5
c=6
A = a,b,c

# Compute inverse
t = sum(A)/(len(A)-2.)
B = [(t-x)*0.5 for x in A]

# Check
x,y,z = B
print -x+y+z
print x-y+z
print x+y-z
```

I derived this formula by:

1. Adding all the equations together to get (N-2)(x+y+z)=(a+b+c) where N is the number of equations
2. Writing each equation as, for example,  -x+y+z = x+y+z - 2x = (a+b+c)/(N-2) - 2x = a
3. Solving this equation for the value of x

Comment: I am not familiar with Python, if possible please give me algorithm or C code.

Comment: @devsda Show some initiative, please. Someone spent quite some time giving you a very detailed answer to your question. All *you* have to do now is look up the very simplest bits of Python syntax. That's not too much to ask.

Comment: @us2012  Really Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your examples, you look like you're trying to invert a n by n matrix of all 1's, except on the diagonal you have -1's. Let's call this matrix D_n.

Given this symmetry, the inverse is going to be similar: all a's, except on the diagonal you'll have b's (a and b to be found).

Multiplying D_n with the inverse gives us two equations that need to be satisfied (corresponding to entries in the product on the diagonal, and off the diagonal).

```
-b + (n-1) * a = 1
b + (n-3) * a = 0
```

Solving gives us:

```
a = 1/(2n - 4)
b = (3-n)/(2n - 4)
```

For example, when n=3, you have a=1/2, b=0, so the inverse, inv(D_3), is

```
0   0.5 0.5
0.5 0   0.5
0.5 0.5 0
```

Or when n=4, you have a=1/4, b=-1/4, so the inverse, inv(D_4), is

```
-0.2500    0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
 0.2500   -0.2500    0.2500    0.2500
 0.2500    0.2500   -0.2500    0.2500
 0.2500    0.2500    0.2500   -0.2500
```

Now, you're trying to find x_1, x_2, ..., x_n (call this vector x) such that D_n * x = (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n).

Given that we've figured out how to compute inv(D_n), the solution is:

```
x_j = (3 - n)a_j / (2n - 4) + sum(i=1..n, i != j) (a_n / (2n - 4))
```